# LINQ Query over heterogeneous collection of different types with same base class

Tags: linq, linq-to-xml

Is there any easy way to query a heterogeneous collection, where the objects in the collection all derive from the same base class but some may be of one derived type and some may be of another?

For example, here's a class hierarchy:

```
public class Ship
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}

public class SailingVessel : Ship
{
    public string Rig { get; set; }
    public int NumberOfMasts { get; set; }
}

public class MotorVessel : Ship
{
    public string Propulsion { get; set; }
    public decimal TopSpeed { get; set; }
}
```

And here's an XML document I want to query:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<ships xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <ship xsi:type="sailingVessel">
    <name>Cutty Sark</name>
    <description>Tea clipper</description>
    <rig>Ship</rig>
    <numberOfMasts>3</numberOfMasts>
  </ship>
  <ship xsi:type="sailingVessel">
    <name>Peking</name>
    <description>Windjammer of the Flying P Line</description>
    <rig>Barque</rig>
    <numberOfMasts>4</numberOfMasts>
  </ship>
  <ship xsi:type="motorVessel">
    <name>HMS Hood</name>
    <description>Last British battlecruiser</description>
    <propulsion>SteamTurbine</propulsion>
    <topSpeed>28</topSpeed>
  </ship>
  <ship xsi:type="motorVessel">
    <name>RMS Queen Mary 2</name>
    <description>Last transatlantic passenger liner</description>
    <propulsion>IntegratedElectricPropulsion</propulsion>
    <topSpeed>30</topSpeed>
  </ship>
  <ship xsi:type="motorVessel">
    <name>USS Enterprise</name>
    <description>First nuclear-powered aircraft carrier</description>
    <propulsion>Nuclear</propulsion>
    <topSpeed>33.6</topSpeed>
  </ship>
</ships>
```

I can query the XML document and read its contents into a list of Ship objects:

```
        XDocument xmlDocument = XDocument.Load("Ships.xml")
        XNamespace xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance";

        var records = (from record in xmlDocument.Descendants("ship")
                       let type = record.Attribute(xsi + "type").Value                         
                       select new Ship
                       {
                           Name = (string)record.Element("name"),
                           Description = (string)record.Element("description")
                       }).ToArray<Ship>();
```

This returns the following:

```
Ship[0] (type: Ship):
    Name: Cutty Sark
    Description: Tea clipper
Ship[1] (type: Ship):
    Name: Peking
    Description: Windjammer of the Flying P Line
Ship[2] (type: Ship):
    Name: HMS Hood
    Description: Last British battlecruiser
Ship[3] (type: Ship):
    Name: RMS Queen Mary 2
    Description: Last transatlantic passenger liner
Ship[4] (type: Ship):
    Name: USS Enterprise
    Description: First nuclear-powered aircraft carrier
```

What I would really like to be able to produce, though, is this:

```
Ship[0] (type: SailingVessel):
    Name: Cutty Sark
    Description: Tea clipper
    Rig: Ship
    NumberOfMasts: 3
Ship[1] (type: SailingVessel):
    Name: Peking
    Description: Windjammer of the Flying P Line
    Rig: Barque
    NumberOfMasts: 4
Ship[2] (type: MotorVessel):
    Name: HMS Hood
    Description: Last British battlecruiser
    Propulsion: SteamTurbine
    TopSpeed: 28
Ship[3] (type: MotorVessel):
    Name: RMS Queen Mary 2
    Description: Last transatlantic passenger liner
    Propulsion: IntegratedElectricPropulsion
    TopSpeed: 30
Ship[4] (type: MotorVessel):
    Name: USS Enterprise
    Description: First nuclear-powered aircraft carrier
    Propulsion: Nuclear
    TopSpeed: 33.6
```

How can I modify the LINQ query to intialize a SailingVessel object or a MotorVessel object as appropriate, instead of a base Ship object?

Do I have to do two selects, and duplicate the object initialization for the base class properties (Name and Description) in each one?  That is all I can think of but I hate the duplication of code involved.  Alternatively, is there some way to initialize the properties for the base class and optionally initialize additional properties for a SailingVessel (Rig, NumberOfMasts) or a MotorVessel (Propulsion, TopSpeed) as appropriate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I would give each type a static `FromXElement` method (or constructor), and then create a `Dictionary<string, Func<Ship>>` like this:

```
var factories = new Dictionary<string, Func<Ship>>
{
     { "sailingVessel", SailingVessel.FromXElement },
     { "motorVessl", MotorVessel.FromXElement },
     ...
};
```

Then your query would be:

```
var records = from record in xmlDocument.Descendants("ship")
              let type = record.Attribute(xsi + "type").Value 
              select factories[type](record);
```

You could give the `Ship` class a protected constructor taking `XElement` to extract the common properties, leaving something like:

```
public class SailingVessel : Ship
{
    public Rig Rig { get; set; }
    public int NumberOfMasts { get; set; }

    private SailingVessel(XElement element) : base(element)
    {
        Rig = (Rig) Enum.Parse(typeof(Rig), (string) element.Element("Rig"));
        NumberOfMasts = (int) element.Element("NumberOfMasts");
    }

    // Don't really need this of course - could put constructor calls
    // into your factory instead. I like the flexibility of factory 
    // methods though, e.g. for caching etc.
    public static FromXElement(element)
    {
        return new SailingVessel(element);
    }
}
```

There will certainly be a fair amount of code involved, but it will all be reasonably simple, and also easy to test.

Comment: Excellent.  I like the way you use the constructors of the base and derived classes to avoid duplication of the code that reads the elements.  Thanks.

Comment: Note for other users: The easiest way to deal with this would have been to deserialize the XML into objects: 1) Use the XSD.exe command-line tool to create an XSD from the XML; 2) Use XSD.exe to create entity classes from the XSD; 3) Use System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize() to deserialize the XML into the entities.  My problem was the powers that be wanted the entity classes to be free from XML serialization attributes.  Perhaps deserialization using TypeMappings would have done it but it seemed to me LINQ was more straight-forward.

Comment: @SimonTewsi: Personally I'm not a huge fan of automated serialization like that. I often find I end up wanting to take more control of the whole process. But YMMV of course :)